# Kotlin - What happens when a range is created using .. or how it performs comparations?

Tags: kotlin, range, conditional-statements, long-integer

I recently noticed a code refactor from:

```
   if (date < minDate || date > maxDate)
```

to

```
if (date !in minDate..maxDate)
```

to which my main worry was that using range would create an "array" or some list of **all the milliseconds** between `minDate` and `maxDate`

I tried researching some of the kotlin internals but couldn't get a final answer on what would happen on that case.

Supposedly:

> In Kotlin `in` checks are translated to the corresponding `contains`
>   calls

Comment: It doesn't create an array. E.g., you can create a string range, which usually contains infinitely many strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it does not create an array of every possible value (because an array would be inefficient for that, even if we did need to store every value, which we don't).

This is the source for the `ClosedRange` interface, which the `..` range operator translates into (comments removed):

```
public interface ClosedRange<T: Comparable<T>> {
    public val start: T
    public val endInclusive: T    
    public fun isEmpty(): Boolean = start > endInclusive

    public operator fun contains(value: T): Boolean = 
        value >= start && value <= endInclusive
}
```

As you can see the type it ranges over (`T`) must implement `Comparable<T>`. This allows the implementation to do a straight comparison of the `value` and the `start` and `endInclusive` of the range. You can see this in the implementation of `contains(value: T)`.

Answer (score 0):

According to `Range` class implementation in kotlin, it won't create a list and comparison will be done as follows (`contains` is called when comparing ranges), based on `LongProgression` class (created on `Long` ranges).

```
/**
 * A range of values of type `Long`.
 */
public class LongRange(start: Long, endInclusive: Long) : LongProgression(start, endInclusive, 1), ClosedRange<Long> {
    override val start: Long get() = first
    override val endInclusive: Long get() = last

    override fun contains(value: Long): Boolean = first <= value && value <= last

    override fun isEmpty(): Boolean = first > last

    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean =
        other is LongRange && (isEmpty() && other.isEmpty() ||
        first == other.first && last == other.last)

    override fun hashCode(): Int =
        if (isEmpty()) -1 else (31 * (first xor (first ushr 32)) + (last xor (last ushr 32))).toInt()

    override fun toString(): String = "$first..$last"

    companion object {
        /** An empty range of values of type Long. */
        public val EMPTY: LongRange = LongRange(1, 0)
    }
}
```